# member? function on infinite lists

Tags: recursion, clojure, lazy-evaluation

I implemented a member? function in clojure as follows:

```
(defn member? [item seq]
  (cond (empty? seq) false
        (= item (first seq)) true
        :else (recur item (rest seq))))
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work with infinite lists. Does anybody know of a way to implement it in order to be able to get:

```
(member? 3 (range)) -> true
```

Comment: why not just use `filter`? e.g. `(boolean (seq (filter #{2} (range 10))))`

Comment: even if it works for positive cases, what do you think `(member? -10 (range))` should return?

Comment: @alfredx This was just a test case: I wanted to make sure that the second argument of member? is not fully realized for performance reasons although in practice I would never supply an unlimited list. I wasn't aware that it *does* work in clojure 1.7.0 (I had tested with clojure 1.6.0, see comment below).

Comment: I feel this is a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I've seen a question like this before when a user tried to port a `unique` function to work on  lazy sequences.

Comment: As an aside, I'd highly discourage you from using 'seq' (or any other name that shadows a function from clojure.core) as a variable name. It works, but is extremely error-prone.

Comment: I copy-pasted your code and (member? 3 (range)) resulted "true" as expected. an you explain your problem a bit clearer?

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation behaves correctly for an infinite input sequence. It does not terminate until an element has been found because the `(empty? seq)` case never falls.

Consider searching for something in an infinite space. When is it a good time to say it isn't there? There is no reliable way to tell. Limit the space you are searching in, e. g.:

```
(member? 3 (take 10 (range)))
```

Answer (score 1):

#### You can't. I mean, at all.

In order to make sure there is no certain element you need to traverse the entire collection. Then and only then you can guarantee it's not there.

In some cases, such as your example, input sequence is ascending, i. e. every element of your sequence is less than its successive element. You can leverage that and make your sequence finite [using `take-while`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/take-while):

```
(member? 3    # is 3 a member of
  (take-while # a sequence of elements
    #(<= % 3) # up to 3 inclusively
    range))   # from range
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, your code already works: `(member? 3 (range))` returns `true`.

But what is the point of checking for the existence of a value in an infinite sequence? It will either return true or it will never return.

Comment: Thanks for the note! My original code was tested with clojure 1.6.0. In clojure 1.7.0 it actually does work. The question was asked because I wanted to make sure, the second argument of my member? function wasn't always fully realized for performance reasons. I'd like to post some code to illlustrate this, but unfortunately the markdown doesn't seem to work and the code is barely readable so I'll refrain from that until I've fully understood why 4 spaces of indentation and 2 spaces at the end of the line in comments don't lead to correctly broken code blocks...

Comment: It worked in Clojure 1.6 too. You must have made some other mistake.